# ElasticSearch Node location updation

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, nodes, graylog2, graylog

I am using graylog1.4 and elasticsearch 2.3,
 I would like to change the location of (cluster indexes) -> /var/lib/elasticsearch/graylog2/nodes/0/indices/graylog2_0/0/index/ -> to an attached storage (like I have SAN storage which is mounted as /data), please suggest where to make changes in configuration to achieve it because this /var/lib/elasticsearch/graylog2 have consumed almost all local disk.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Graylog are you using? There is no Graylog 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of the Elasticsearch indices on disk using the `path.data` configuration setting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-configuration.html#paths